# Parsing and structuring VBScript into Python code using Python

Tags: python, regex, vbscript

I'm a beginner to programming and was wondering about the simplest way to do this.

I have VBS code and I want to translate it into python code, using a python script.

Sample code:

```
oDesign.ChangeProperty Array("NAME:AllTabs", Array("NAME:LocalVariableTab", Array("NAME:PropServers", "LocalVariables"), Array("NAME:NewProps", Array("NAME:ps2pad", "PropType:=", "VariableProp", "UserDef:=", true, "Value:=", "31mil")), Array("NAME:ChangedProps", Array("NAME:ps2pad", "Hidden:=", false))))
```

To be changed into Python script, it needs to look more like this:

```
oDesign.ChangeProperty(
[
    "NAME:AllTabs",
    [
        "NAME:LocalVariableTab",
        [
            "NAME:PropServers", 
            "LocalVariables"
        ],
        [
            "NAME:NewProps",
            [
                "NAME:ps1drill",
                "PropType:="        , "VariableProp",
                "UserDef:="     , True,
                "Value:="       , "17.7mil"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "NAME:ChangedProps",
            [
                "NAME:ps1drill",
                "Hidden:="      , False,
                "Value:="       , "17.7mil"
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

This isn't exact code, but it's fairly close to what I'm working with.
As you can see, there are only a few differences: all of the "Array" statements must be discarded, a few parentheses are added, and a bracket is added.

I was thinking about using regex, but that seems a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the merits of doing what you're trying, but if you just want to turn this into valid python code, you could start by:

- assigning false to False
- assigning true to True
- creating an `Array` function or class
- creating a class, with a ChangeProperty method, and instantiating oDesign as an instance

Then adding a single '(' after ChangeProperty, and another single ')' at the end of your sample code would compile:

eg.

```
import pprint

class Design:
    def ChangeProperty(*val):
        pprint.pprint(val)

true = True
false = False
Array = lambda * v: v
oDesign = Design()

# now with the simple addition of the two parentheses I mentioned above, 
# your VBS code is valid python.

oDesign.ChangeProperty(Array("NAME:AllTabs", Array("NAME:LocalVariableTab", Array("NAME:PropServers", "LocalVariables"), Array("NAME:NewProps", Array("NAME:ps2pad", "PropType:=", "VariableProp", "UserDef:=", true, "Value:=", "31mil")), Array("NAME:ChangedProps", Array("NAME:ps2pad", "Hidden:=", false)))))
```

# is now valid python code and prints this (on my system):

```
(<__main__.Design instance at 0x000000000248AF08>,
 ('NAME:AllTabs',
  ('NAME:LocalVariableTab',
   ('NAME:PropServers', 'LocalVariables'),
   ('NAME:NewProps',
    ('NAME:ps2pad',
     'PropType:=',
     'VariableProp',
     'UserDef:=',
     True,
     'Value:=',
     '31mil')),
   ('NAME:ChangedProps', ('NAME:ps2pad', 'Hidden:=', False)))))
```